# SwiftUI iOS14 - NavigationView + List - Won't fill space

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, ios14, swiftui-navigationview

I'm having an issues with a List inside a NavigationView since iOS 14 update.

Here is a simple breakdown of the code - I've striped everything that doesn't show the issue

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var views = ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                
                List {
                    
                    ForEach(views, id: \.self) { view in
                       
                        VStack {
                        Text("\(view)")
                        }
                        .background(Color.red)
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

This produces the following result:

[image: list inside nav vew]

I cant work out why the list is hovering in the center of the navigation view like that. As far as I can tell this should produce a listview that takes up all avaliable space (with the exception of the top where navigationbar would be).

Indeed when run on iOS 13.5 that is the result I get as pictured below:

[image: list in nav view 2]

I've had a read through the documentation but cant work out why this behaviour is suddenly happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

#### Problem

It looks like the default styles of a `List` or `NavigationView` in iOS 14 may in some cases be different than in iOS 13.

#### Solution #1 - explicit *listStyle*

It's no longer always the `PlainListStyle` (as in iOS 13) but sometimes the `InsetGroupedListStyle` as well.

You need to explicitly specify the `listStyle` to `PlainListStyle`:

```
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var views = ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(views, id: \.self) { view in
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(view)")
                        }
                        .background(Color.red)
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle()) // <- add here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Solution #2 - explicit *navigationViewStyle*

It looks like the NavigationView's default style can sometimes be the `DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle` (even on iPhones).

You can try setting the `navigationViewStyle` to the `StackNavigationViewStyle` (as in iOS 13):

```
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var views = ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(views, id: \.self) { view in
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(view)")
                        }
                        .background(Color.red)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) // <- add here
    }
}
```

Comment: In my project the inset only seems to happen when using `ForEach` inside `List`. Just using `List` + `.listStyle(PlainListStyle())` does not show the inset. Anyone can confirm this?

Comment: @koen In the above example, when wrapped in a VStack, both `List` and `List+ForEach` are with insets. Only removing the VStack or setting the `.listStyle` explicitly removes the insets. Unfortunately it's not well documented (yet?) when the `InsetGroupedListStyle` is the default style.

Comment: @pawello2222 Hmm, I have a VStack with a (custom) `SearchBarView` and a `List`, the default `listStyle`, and it does not show the inset. Maybe the extra view has something to do with it. Anyway, thanks for the pointer to using `PlainListStyle()`.