# SwiftUI - How to remove white background behind List that is styled with SidebarListStyle, in portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have a list styled with [`SidebarListStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/sidebarliststyle) (new in iOS 14) inside a `NavigationView`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let data = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Section")) {
                    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { word in
                        Text(word)
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"), displayMode: .large)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that there is a white rectangle behind each of the rows in the list, but only in portrait mode. It's fine in landscape.

[image] [image]

I don't want that white background, anyone know **how to remove it**? Also, when launching the app, it seems to glitch -- at first it's fine, then it adds the white background.

[image]

Weirdly, if I add `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` to the `NavigationView`, the white background disappears and it launches fine.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let data = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Section")) {
                    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { word in
                        Text(word)
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"), displayMode: .large)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Left: How it launches, right: How it looks after launching

[image] [image]

#### ↑ This is how I want it to be.

However, now the landscape mode is limited to a full-width list, which I don't want either.

[image]

#### Edit: [@Omid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13899957/omid)'s answer

I added a background color to match the default one:

```
Text(word)
.listRowBackground(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
```

But the launching glitch is still there.

[image]

#### Edit: [@pawello2222](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8697793/pawello2222)'s answer

Works alright, just a weird transition when rotating.

[image]

Comment: could you explain more? now you have Row backgroundColor issue or animation on lunch? tell me what you you want happen?

Comment: I have 2 issues combined in one, kind of. When it launches, the row flickers from a clear to white background. I want it to launch without the flicker, and stay with a clear background. I'll add a gif

Comment: you can not change that fickers it is backed to animation on SwiftUI

Comment: @Omid huh, that's weird...

Comment: this wightish animation is over all in swifttui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem

> Weirdly, if I add .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) to
> the NavigationView, the white background disappears and it launches
> fine.

This is because in iOS 14 the default styles of `NavigationView` or `List` are no longer always the same. See:

- [SwiftUI iOS14 - NavigationView + List - Won't fill space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63938471/8697793)

---

#### Solution

You can use a different `NavigationStyle` depending on the `@Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass)`:

```
struct CustomNavigationStyle: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass

    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
            content.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        } else {
            content.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

```
NavigationView {
    ...
}
.modifier(CustomNavigationStyle())
```

Comment: Nice! Works great, but unfortunately there's now a weird animation when going from portrait to landscape and back. That's ok though I guess, see the edit to my post

Answer (score 2):

you can change the color to what you want!

```
Text(word)
  .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found something else though -- when I first launch the app, for a split second it's fine, but then suddenly there's a white background. When I tried your answer, the same thing happened. See the edit to my post